# Unable download speech language in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, language-pack, text-to-speech, cortana

I want the English UK speech language in my Windows 10 PC in order to make Cortana work.

The display language English UK got downloaded, but the speech and handwriting languages options are showing errors:

[image: Here is the Screenshot].

I also tried installing the language pack from a lp.cab file. But it showed this error:

[image: this error]

Tried Language Pack for 10586 build too.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dism /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\lp.cab

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.10586.0

Image Version: 10.0.10586.0

Processing 1 of 1 - Adding package Microsoft-Windows-Client-LanguagePack-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-GB~10.0.10586.0
[==========================100.0%==========================]
An error occurred - Microsoft-Windows-Client-LanguagePack-Package Error: 0x8007000d

Error: 13

The data is invalid.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

Can anybody help me out with this problem. I will be very thankful.

Comment: When you click "More Details" under the errors in the GUI, what does it tell you?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007  It takes me to "Manage Optional Features" where pr-installed language packs are given...

It does the same if I click on the notification "Something happened and we couldn't install the feature"...

Comment: the 9926 LPs can't be used on Win10 Build 10586. use the correct MUI packs: http://winaero.com/blog/download-mui-language-packs-for-windows-10-build-10586/

Comment: @magicandre1981 does en-GB pack contain speech language???

Comment: I have no idea. try it out with the new MUIs

Comment: Hi @magicandre1981 I tried the LP for 10586 build. But got a different error this time... Please see the edited question... Thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem Solved!**

Actually I was using **Mobile Hotspot** to download.

*Windows 10 does not allow us to download language packs over a metered connection unless you enable downloads over metered connections from Settings*.

The language pack was downloaded when I connected my PC to a **WiFi network**.

Later I downloaded English (India) too. Cortana is working fine now.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem where the only *Speech* language available was US English and Windows would not let me download UK English speech in order to match my Region and get Cortana to work.

I solved it with a temporary registry edit to force Windows Update to re-download all the UK language files including speech. Usual Disclaimer: "Do not attempt this unless you are comfortable editing the registry/stopping services and risking wrecking your Windows installation!"

1. In Settings open the 'Time & Language' section and go to the 'Region and Language' page.
2. Run Regedit (as an administrator) and rename `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate` key to something else, e.g. `WindowsUpdateXXX`
3. Run services.msc from the search box and stop the 'Windows Update'   service (right-click it)
4. Go back to 'Region and Language' and click your language (UK) and then the Options button
5. Download all the options: Basic Typing, Handwriting, Speech
6. Once downloaded, go to the 'Speech' page and you should see now be able to select your language there (UK)
7. Stop the 'Windows Update' Service again
8. Rename the registry key back to 'WindowsUpdate'
9. The WindowsUpdate service will restart itself eventually or you can start it if you like
10. Run Cortana and it should work, now that all your languages are the same (and supported)!

Comment: This does not only work Speech language. In my case I wanted to install Graphics Tools, but the Optional Features list didn't show anything. This is the best answer so far. Found this post via [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/no-features-to-install-under-optional-features/83d8268a-26c5-4008-911a-ded2ecc30537) and it worked.

Comment: This seemed to work on my machine where I couldn't install any language options for any language, especially Basic Typing. Wonder what the actual underlying issue is...

Comment: Still worked for my problem after 5 year

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU` there's a value called `UseWUServer`. I changed it to `0`, restarted the Windows update service, after that it worked.
Don't forget to change the value back to `1` and restart windows update service.